# How can I set the float type x.5 in Rating Bar?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. the problem is that I can't see half rating of rating bar.
For example,there is  ratingbar set numStar="5",stepSize="0.5",isIndicator="true".
and then I used RatingBar method:setRating and set rating=2.5. 
I thought this RatingBar will show me  2start+a half star. 
but this rating bar expressed 3 start. I can't figure it out.. somebody help me..

example code :

```
RatingBar rt =(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingbar1);
rt.setNumStart=5;
rt.setStepSize=0.5f;
rt.setRating(2.5f);
```

Comment: Can you format your code exactly as you did in your project?

Answer (score 0):

```
RatingBar rt =(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
rt.setIsIndicator(true);
rt.setNumStars(5);
rt.setStepSize(0.5f);
rt.setRating(2.5f);
```

I used the same code and it is working for me. It is probably a bug, or maybe there is a problem while trying to set the rating. If you are setting the value from a variable, then try
`rt.setRating((float) var)`
[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7y7k.png)

UPDATE: Setting max value seems to solve the problem for some users, try`rt.setMax(5)`

Comment: thank you for your reply!  I tried everything I can do but I could not solve this problem. I want to get average of two float type variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
float aveRating=totalSum/totalIndex;

        float refRat= (float) (aveRating-(Math.floor(aveRating)));
        float setRat=0;

        if(refRat>=0.7){
            setRat=Math.round(aveRating);
            Toast.makeText(this,"0.7이상:"+ setRat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(refRat<0.7 && refRat>=0.3){
            setRat= (float) (Math.floor(aveRating)+(float)0.5);
            Toast.makeText(this,"0.7이하 0.5이상 :" + setRat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(refRat<0.3){
            setRat= (float) Math.floor(aveRating);
            Toast.makeText(this," 0.5이하:"+ setRat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        String stringAveRat = String.format("%.1f" , aveRating);

        ksRatingBar.setRating((float)setRat);
        ksRatingText.setText(stringAveRat);
```